# Is this a typo or alternative notation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I am reading *Calculus:Volume II* by Chen, Liu, etc.

on page 201, the book states this.

> ...For example, $$ y^{\prime\prime} +xy^{\prime 3} + 5y = e^x $$ is a third-order equation.

I have seen $y^{(3)}$ as meaning the third derivative of y in prime notation; however, I have never seen $y^{\prime N}$ where $N$ is a natural numer for the $N$th derivative of a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the terminology employed for algebraic differential equations

$$\rm  a\, y^{e_0} (y')^{e_1}\cdots (y^{(k)}\!)^{e_k} $$

- has $ $ *order* $\rm\,\ k$
- has $ $ *degree* $\rm\,\ e_0 + e_1 + \cdots + e_k$
- has $ $ *weight* $\rm\,\ e_0 + 2 e_2 + \cdots + (k+1) e_k$

A differential polynomial is a sum of such differential monomials. It's order is the maximum order of any of its monomials. Similarly for its degree and weight.

Comment: What exactly is weight in this context? How is that different than degree?

Comment: @MaoYiyi The weight incorporates information about both the degree and order, so it serves a different purpose than the degree. For a simple example, the weight serves as a convenient measure for various inductive proofs that depend on both the degree and order.

Answer (score 6):

This is definitely a second order equation and $y'^3$ means the cube of $y'$.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but I am just learning this so I asked the question. I am thinking the authors wanted $y^{\left(3\right)}$

Comment: No, then probably $y^{(3)}$ or $y'''$ would have been written.

Comment: @berci, then why would the author say its a "third-order equation"?